как сделать выбор таблицы перед запросом в peewee
В базе данных sqlite3 есть таблица, выглядит следующим образом:
class PlansFiles(Model):
id = PrimaryKeyField(unique=True)
fname = CharField()
fpath = CharField()

class Meta:
    database = db
    order_by = 'fname'
    db_table = 'plans_files'

написано уже много кода, и во многих методах уже прописаны необходимые запросы, что-то вроде этого:
inst_plansfiles = PlansFiles.get(PlansFiles.fname == cur_item)

Теперь появилась необходимость добавить еще аналогичную таблицу с такими именами столбцов, но другими данными. И при необходимости нужно переключаться между ними. То есть сегодня мне нужно делать поиск только по первой таблице, а завтра только по второй. Как это правильно сделать чтоб не переписывать все методы?
Например добавляю вторую таблицу (с индексом 2):
class PlansFiles2(Model):
id = PrimaryKeyField(unique=True)
fname = CharField()
fpath = CharField()

class Meta:
    database = db
    order_by = 'fname'
    db_table = 'plans_files'

Как теперь в уже рабочем приложении во все имеющиеся запросы в коде подставить нужное имя таблицы? Или можно написать какой-нибудь метод который будет это делать?
